# How do I listen for a number value in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I have made a shopping cart in react. I have assigned a value to each button. The value shows in the dom so I know it's there.

I created a function to capture the value and then push it into an array. However, when I hit add to cart it say's "nothing added". I've been trying to find a way to listen for the value in the event listener but nothing seems to work.

I have tried putting just e.target.value but the outcome is the same.

Any ideas?

```
const [item, setItem] = useState([]);

function addCart(e) {
    if (e.target.value === "") {
      item.push(e.target.value);
      console.log(item);
      setCart(cart + 1);
    } else {
      console.log("nothing added");
    }
  }

 <button
              value={pro.price}
              onClick={addCart}
              className="bg-blue-500 text-white font-bold border-white p-2 rounded-md"
            >
              {"add to cart"}
            </button>
```

Comment: You have a state function called `setItem` that you're not using.

Comment: `if (e.target.value === "") {` - So... only add the value to the array if the value is empty?  If `pro.price` has any value other than an empty string then this would always invoke the `else` block.  Was that just a typo?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to negate the condition in the `if` block. `e.target.value !== ""`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update your state `item`, you've to use `setItem`.

```
function addCart(e) {
    if (e.target.value !== "") {
      setItem([...item, e.target.value]);
      console.log(item);
      setCart(cart + 1);
    } else {
      console.log("nothing added");
    }
  }
```

Comment: sorry, why do i need setItem? im still learning coming from just vanilla js. I added the '!==' and that performed what i needed.

Comment: When you say it "works", do you mean your `cart` state is correctly incremented ? If so, yes it works. But your `item` state has been mutated using `push` which returns the lenght of the new array and not an array. In React, you've to use setters functions to update states.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you could change your approach and use a `class` instead of a `function` as such :

```js
class AddCard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      value: 'VALUE'
    }
  }
  handleChange (e) {
    console.log('handleChange called')
  }
  handleClick () {
    this.setState({value: 'UPDATED_VALUE'})
    var event = new Event('input', { bubbles: true });
    this.myinput.dispatchEvent(event);
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <input readOnly value={this.state.value} onChange={(e) => {this.handleChange(e)}} ref={(input)=> this.myinput = input}/>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>Change Input</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<AddCard />,  document.getElementById('app'))
```

By doing so you'll be able to dissociate the `click` event and the `change` event